# Amazon Datawarehouse architecture and design

Tags: amazon-s3, data-warehouse

I have some flight booking data in a Sql server table with booking for a passenger.

The below query highlights all the tables involved along with joins

```
"SELECT distinct * FROM 
Booking B 
JOIN BookingPassenger BP
    ON B.BookingId = BP.BookingId
JOIN PassengerJourneyLeg PJL
    ON PJL.PassengerId = BP.PassengerId
JOIN InventoryLeg IL
    ON IL.InventoryLegId = PJL.InventoryLegId
join passengerjourneysegment ps
    on ps.PassengerId=  BP.PassengerId
WHERE IL.departuredate = '2014/03/26' and il.flightnumber = 123
AND B.CreatedDate < '2014/03/22'"
```

Now Revenue departments needs this data to be put into a Data Warehouse so that they can compute a booking curve for each flight on any day or all flights on any day or within specific dates. Currently they are doing it via excel which fetches data through sql but it is very time consuming and does not give real time data. Later they want to gather data from our corporate booking website and want to manage customer profile on this data warehouse which will be our main analytical platform. I am fresh to data warehouse and learning and researching on how to implement a effective data-warehouse to meet their needs.

Can someone help me on How should i collect the data ? Should i upload it into dynamodb or s3 and what is the best way to do that as one time job and as recurring job?

The later aim of this data warehouse will be to plot all information related to the PNR. Flight revenue by day, by class, by subclass, by event etc.

Later phase, every time user interact with our website, i want to store that in redshift.. so when should i write the files to S3 or dynamodb? and how many ? i.e : -  If i do write files to S3 on each user event, i will end up with hundreds of files, that may not seems like a good solution. What about introducing RDS or dynamodb to store each transaction? or is it possible to allow server log files to store info (user interaction on website) and doing any event (booking, cancel etc) to be recorded into RDS or Dynamodb?

what are the best practices ? What may be the best design in my specific scenario? Also if someone can please give more clarify on How can that be implemented?

what are the best practices to have reports with 1-5 TB of data to come back in few minutes or seconds and avoid any duplication or latency?

Also can someone suggest how can have ease of maintenance and have the cost effectiveness and at par with some the best solutions?

I will really appreciate any help, links, suggestion on the topics of Data warehousing, Amazon (Redshift,s3, Dynamo Db) technologies specific to my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions, i suspect that some of them was answered due the elapsed time. Anyway, let me explain my thougths about this.

> Later they want to gather data from our corporate booking website and want to manage customer profile on this data warehouse which will be our main analytical platform

- Establish a staging area database is a good idea, a "database for drafts". You can create simple tables to deal with this data.

> Can someone help me on How should i collect the data ? Should i upload it into dynamodb or s3 and what is the best way to do that as one time job and as recurring job?

- A good path is to use some ETL tool to collect the data. I like Pentaho CE and its PDI.

> Later phase, every time user interact with our website, i want to store that in redshift.. so when should i write the files to S3 or dynamodb? and how many ? i.e : - If i do write files to S3 on each user event, i will end up with hundreds of files, that may not seems like a good solution. What about introducing RDS or dynamodb to store each transaction? or is it possible to allow server log files to store info (user interaction on website) and doing any event (booking, cancel etc) to be recorded into RDS or Dynamodb?

- I prefer the last idea. Store your server log and time by time copy to the staging database keeping the more amount of log you can for statistical purposes in the staging area. In my opinion it is the most common practice.

> what are the best practices ? What may be the best design in my specific scenario? Also if someone can please give more clarify on How can that be implemented?

- Take a look at this answer on this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/a/2015115/2249963 (I just didn´t want to copy and paste as if it was my answer, so i agree :) )

> what are the best practices to have reports with 1-5 TB of data to come back in few minutes or seconds and avoid any duplication or latency?

- There are many ways to do this, basically duplication is used and latency is the counterpart of the performance. You really need to elect how many time it is required to analyse your data. The previous day, also called D-1 is usual.

> Also can someone suggest how can have ease of maintenance and have the cost effectiveness and at par with some the best solutions?

- Doing a good design on model and keep things simple, as in everything on IT.

I hope it can help